# Query httpservice from ActionScript class

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, mxml

I'm trying to get the result from my httpservice (defined in an AS class) back to my mxml application. The code itself works fine when I put everything in the main mxml but I can't seem to get it working from my AS class.

When I put a breakpoint on the line where I fetch the httpresult (myWatchedList = new XMLListCollection(myData.movie);) I can confirm that myWatchedList has the desired values. However myWatchedList is always null when I invoke the getWatchedList() method.

I'm sure I'm missing something very obvious here...

My AS class:

```
package components
{

import mx.collections.XMLListCollection;
import mx.rpc.events.ResultEvent;
import mx.rpc.http.HTTPService;

public class WatchList
{
    [Bindable]
    public var myToWatchList:XMLListCollection;
    public var myWatchedList:XMLListCollection;

    public function WatchList()
    {
        //httpservice for watched movies
        var watchedList_service:HTTPService = new HTTPService();
        watchedList_service.url= "http://*****/phpscripts/selectWatchedlist.php";
        watchedList_service.showBusyCursor=true;
        watchedList_service.resultFormat="e4x";
        watchedList_service.method="POST";  

        //httpservice for not yet watched movies
        var toWatchList_service:HTTPService = new HTTPService();
        toWatchList_service.url= "http://*****/phpscripts/selectToWatchlist.php";
        toWatchList_service.showBusyCursor=true;
        toWatchList_service.resultFormat="e4x";
        toWatchList_service.method="POST";

        //listen for result
        watchedList_service.addEventListener(ResultEvent.RESULT, watchedList_result);
        toWatchList_service.addEventListener(ResultEvent.RESULT, toWatchList_result);

        //send request to httpservice
        toWatchList_service.send();
        watchedList_service.send();     

    }

    public function toWatchList_result(event:ResultEvent):void
    {
        //result is xml
        var myData:XML = XML(event.result);
        myWatchedList = new XMLListCollection(myData.movie);
    }

    public function watchedList_result(event:ResultEvent):void
    {
        var myData:XML = XML(event.result);
        myToWatchList = new XMLListCollection(myData.movie);
    }

    public function getWatchedList():XMLListCollection {
        return this.myWatchedList;
    }

    public function getToWatchList():XMLListCollection {
        return this.myToWatchList;
    }
}
}
```

The code in the mxml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:Application xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
           xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
           xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx" minWidth="955" minHeight="600"
           xmlns:components="components.*"
           initialize="doSend()">
<s:layout>
    <s:VerticalLayout paddingBottom="20" paddingLeft="20"
                      paddingRight="20" paddingTop="20"/>
</s:layout>
<fx:Script> 
    <![CDATA[
        import components.WatchList;
        import mx.collections.XMLListCollection;

        [Bindable]
        private var myToWatchList:XMLListCollection;
        private var myWatchedList:XMLListCollection;
        private var watchList:components.WatchList;
        protected function doSend():void 
        {
            watchList= new components.WatchList();
            //fetch the watchlists
            myToWatchList = watchList.getToWatchList();
            myWatchedList = watchList.getWatchedList();

            //bind the watchlists to the tilelist
            myToWatchList_tile.dataProvider = myToWatchList;
            myWatchedList_tile.dataProvider = myWatchedList;
        }


    ]]>

</fx:Script>
<fx:Declarations>
</fx:Declarations>
<s:Panel id="panel"  width="100%" height="100%" title="Watchlist">
    <s:layout>
        <s:VerticalLayout paddingBottom="5" paddingLeft="20"
                          paddingRight="20" paddingTop="5"/>
    </s:layout>
    <s:Label width="20%" fontSize="17" fontWeight="bold" text="Your watched movies"/>
    <mx:TileList id="myWatchedList_tile" height="360" borderVisible="false"
                 columnCount="6" columnWidth="200"
                 itemRenderer="components.TileListItemRenderer" rowCount="1" rowHeight="360"/>
    <s:Label width="20%" fontSize="17" fontWeight="bold" text="Your to watch movies"/>
    <mx:TileList id="myToWatchList_tile"  height="360" borderVisible="false" 
                 columnCount="6" columnWidth="200"
                 itemRenderer="components.TileListItemRenderer" rowCount="1" rowHeight="360" />

</s:Panel>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first you call your constructor where you make the request:

```
watchList= new components.WatchList();
```

and immediately after that you call the results:

```
myToWatchList = watchList.getToWatchList();
```

... you should wait until the request is finished, eg: throw an event when the results are fetched, and make a handler which waits for the event

Comment: Thx, this worked. I dispatch an event now in watchedList_result(event:ResultEvent) and listen to this in my mxml app.